# hive table:Auto Purge property

Tags: hive

I am in learning phase of Hive. I read if we use auto purge property on table , it means data won't go into trash.Can we access the data of that table after overwriting it with new data, if auto purge property is set to true?

Answer (score 1):

No, You will not be able to access data if you set `"auto.purge"="true"` property in Hive table. Usually, it's rarely used because you want data to go to Trash directory in case you deleted them accidently and then `Trash` will automatically remove older files depending on the policy set.